# How to call out the date of user's first comment?

Tags: comments, comment-form, comments-template

For example, Sam's first comment was posted in 2010. How can I show this next to his name in the comment section?

Like this:

SAM [Joined since 2010]

**Update**: Sorry for the unclear question. I am asking about Guest's comments.

Comment: you can use this filter : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_list_comments_args/ In the `walker` argument, you can put a custom walker instead of `Walker_Comment` to customize the comments display.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that from the DB user table, On the image I marked that field.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this user registration time? I am asking about the first comment time of guests :D